# Write to Global Settings in Android 4.2

Tags: android, settings, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Android 4.2 has introduced a new class, [Settings.Global](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html), which now holds some of the settings that used to be in [Settings.Secure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html) or [Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html).

Writing to System Settings and Secure Settings was (and is) possible because or the WRITE_SETTINGS and WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permissions (see [Manifest.permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SECURE_SETTING)).

The thing is... is there any way to modify Global Settings? For example, Airplane mode could before be toggled from an app and now, since it's in Settings.Global, it does not seem possible :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK, you can modify `Settings.Global` the same way you modify `Settings.Secure`: by creating an app that is signed by the firmware's signing key or is installed on the system partition, so it can hold `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`. The difference between `Settings.Global` and `Settings.Secure`, as I understand it, is that the latter is now on a per-user basis, while the global ones are device-wide.

Comment: So... does that mean that from Android 4.2 on there is no way to toggle airplane mode from a normal app? :(