# How to Assign a Quick Launch Hotkey to a Specific App on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to set a quicklaunch shortcut key for my app.

I am able to bring up the Quick Launch screen with the following code:

```
launchIntent = new Intent();
launchIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
launchIntent.setPackage("com.android.settings");
launchIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.quicklaunch.QuickLaunchSettings"));
startActivityForResult(launchIntent,0);
```

The screen looks like this: [Quick Launch Screenshot](http://cdn3.mos.techradar.com///classifications/gadgets/phones/mobile-phones/Android/androidtips/quick-launch-320-100.jpg). You can assign an app to, for example, "a", and when you press find-a, it will launch that app.

What I'd really like to do is to programmatically assign a hotkey to a specific app, but I cannot figure out how to do this. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Thanks for the respond Stephan.But is there anyway to automate the process of assigning the package to the quicklaunch shortcut key instead of having the user manually going through the process?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't seem to be the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416695/write-to-global-settings-in-android-4-2 If you do find a workaround, please do tell us about it. I'd be curious to know too.